# Negative eulerAngles in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am creating a basic car wheel for my game in unity 4.6. I am getting `steerAngle` for my wheels using `eulerAngles.z` of steering. But there is a problem, whenever i rotate steering clockwise then angle it gives me is 360,359,358,etc & i want something like -1,-2,-3,etc. Is there any way to achieve this?

**BTW this is what i've done so far:**

```
    float steerAngle = (steering.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    frontLeftWheel.steerAngle = steerAngle;
    frontRightwheel.steerAngle = steerAngle;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (steerAngle > 180)
    steerAngle -= 360;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I can't believe how easy it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you create an extension method to achieve this?

```
frontLeftWheel.steerAngle = steerAngle.Adjusted();
```

...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private const float MAX_VAL = 360.0;
    public static float AdjustedAngle(
        this Vector3 eulerAngle, int idx = 2)
    {
        /* idx 0 = x
               1 = y
               2 = z */
        //float axesVal = idx == 0 
        //    ? eulerAngle.x 
        //    : idx == 1 ? eulerAngle.y : eulerAngle.z;

        /* need to differentiate between a valid 359, 
           and an invalid 359, which should be returned as 
           359 - 360 or -1 */
        //var valid = <do some work>; 

        // return valid ? axesVal : axesVal - MAX_VAL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the angle is smaller than 180 degree return the same value, but if greater than 180 degree you should -360. So, now you can get the negative value.

```
float steerAngle = (steering.transform.eulerAngles.z < 180f) ? steering.transform.eulerAngles.z : steering.transform.eulerAngles.z - 360;
```